# Turn comma-separate rows into 1 column

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a list of users basically from /etc/group, Id like to basically format that line into one column, I just need the users. So if a field looks like this:

```
bob,john,jane,sam,joyce
```

Then I'd like it to look like this

```
bob
john
jane
sam
joyce
```

I know how to do the opposite but not this type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with sed:

```
sed 's/,/\n/g'
```

This replaces all occurrences of `,` with a newline. `g` makes sed replace all the occurrences in a line instead of just the first.

Comment: Ok this worked. But what if I have a list of rows like:
`group1:x:500:bob,john,jane,sam,joyce`

`group2:x:501:jim,sean,fred,will,thomas`

How can I get  them formatted with some break between  the groups?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: You can chain two sed calls together, one that strips everything up to and including last colon, and second one as per the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer using your suggested tags:

bash:

```
$ IFS=, read -a names <<< "bob,john,jane,sam,joyce"
$ printf "%s\n" "${names[@]}"
bob
john
jane
sam
joyce
```

awk:

```
$ echo "bob,john,jane,sam,joyce" | awk -F, -v OFS="\n" '{$1=$1; print}'
bob
john
jane
sam
joyce
```

The `$1=$1` bit is an awk idiom to rewrite the current record using the Output Field Separators, which does not happen unless some field is modified.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a find and replace in `vim`:

`:%s/,/\r/g`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323/how-to-replace-a-character-for-a-newline-in-vim) question...

Comment: I need to use this in a script so I couldnt do it in vim

Comment: Any help please

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

**tr**:

```
tr ',' '\n' < [input file] > [output file]
```

tr is a tool that filters its standard input and replaces every occurrence of a character from its first argument with the matching one from the second element, then prints to standard out.

**vim/ex** (this will work in a script):

```
vim -c "%s/,/\r/g" -c "wq" [input file]
```

The -c option tells vim to run the following `ex` command (same as what you would type after a `:` when using vim normally).

And someone already beat me to sed.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use awk (similar to [Print all Fields with AWK separated by OFS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13705660/3102264)):

```
echo "bob,john,jane,sam,joyce" | awk  'BEGIN {FS=","; OFS="\n"} {$1=$1; print $0}'
```